# Popup horizontally animate

Tags: react-native, expo

My snack:

https://snack.expo.io/@sitenative/popup-modal-example

Popup open from bottom to top. When gesturing from left to right or conversely popup closed from top to bottom. How to make horizontal animation from left to right or vice versa depending on the user's gesture?

Answer (score 0):

Gestures can be recorded by using React-Native's PanResponder API. You can use PanResponder and Animated API to get the desired Result.

you can check a examples from here!.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations

Comment: in PanResponder i get X moving. I am interested in horizontal animation.